# Different ways of naming functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object, naming-conventions

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between these two functions. Are they the same? It seems like in the first case, appleOne is the name of the object, and in the second case, appleTwo is the name of the function. However, I read that functions and objects are the same in Javascript, so I'm confused...

```
var appleOne = new function(color) {
    this.color = color;
}

function appleTwo (color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

Reference: Code from http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the object associated with the variable `appleTwo` is a function object, which the object associated with the variable `appleOne` is *not* a function: it is a "regular" object with the field `color`.

I wouldn't say that "functions and objects are the same" in JavaScript. What *is* true is that there are several kinds of objects in JavaScript:

- regular objects
- arrays
- functions
- regular expressions

In the first example, you used an anonymous function as a constructor, so the object you produced and assigned to `appleOne` is a "regular" object. The second example uses a *function declaration* to define a function.

If your question was not about the difference, but rather *why* the first case "works" (because it is not a very common pattern), there are several S.O. questions available with the answer.

Comment: Also, since no value is assigned to *color*, then `appleOne.color` is undefined.

Comment: Correct, that's a good thing to add to the answer. The answer itself holds because `Object.keys(appleOne) === ['color']`. But yes, the value is `undefined`.